# How to pass an image using PInvoke

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I have a C DLL which does some processing on an image and returns the result. So I am trying to pass an image over from the .NET side, but right now I am stuck, and I'm not sure whether that's on the types, the intricacies of marshaling, or syntax. Since I am a noob it could be all three.

I can call other functions in the DLL in question, so at least some of the foundations are in place. For example, when I call:

```
IntPtr versionIntPtr = GetDLLVersionNumber();
string version = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(versionIntPtr);
Console.WriteLine("DLL version number reported as: " + version);
```

and this works absolutely fine, printing the current version of the DLL to the console.

When I look at C code sample which uses the same function, it appears to use the function as follows:

```
unsigned char* ExtractImageInfo(const char* pixels, size_t width, size_t height)
```

(I also have a header file where the same function is mentioned as follows:

```
... ExtractImageInformation(struct ImageData image, void* imageInformation);
```

but I don't really know what this means.)

So my attempt to use this function goes as follows:

First I specify the interface to the DLL:

```
[DllImport("C:\\MyDLL", EntryPoint = "ExtractImageInfo", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern IntPtr ExtractImageInfo(IntPtr image, UInt32 imageWidth, UInt32 imageHeight);
```

Then, I get an image of the right type and get its dimensions:

```
Bitmap bitmap1 = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile("C:\\Images\\myImage.bmp");
UInt32 _imageWidth = Convert.ToUInt32(bitmap1.Width);
UInt32 _imageHeight = Convert.ToUInt32(bitmap1.Height);
```

Then I get a pointer to the image (since I think that's what I need to pass):

```
IntPtr bitmap1Ptr = bitmap1.GetHbitmap();
```

And then I call the function...

```
IntPtr myProcessedImage;
myProcessedImage = ExtractImageInfo(bitmap1Ptr, _imageWidth, _imageHeight);
```

But it doesn't work - I don't get back a pointer to my processed data. A big part of what I'm wondering here is whether I am passing the image in the right way, and whether the syntax for my interface to the native function is right. I think probably the answer to both could be NO!

I've only had a few days of reading and experimenting with PInvoke, so if anyone can point out to me the error of my ways I will be eternally grateful :-)

Comment: From the looks of it, your native dll is exposing many memory leaks...

Answer (score 3):

```
 unsigned char* ExtractImageInfo(const char* pixels, size_t width, size_t height)
```

The name of the argument strongly suggests it wants a pointer to the raw pixel data.  You can get one from Bitmap.LockBits(), BitmapData.Scan0 property.  Don't call UnlockBits() until the function returns.

The return type of the function is a significant memory management problem.  Whatever buffer pointer is returned is almost certainly going to have to be released.  You cannot do so from managed code, you don't have access to the allocator used by this C code to call the proper version of free().  Call this function a million times and double-check that you don't have an out-of-control memory leak.  If you do then you can't pinvoke it, a C++/CLI wrapper is required although the odds that it works correctly are fairly slim as well.  This is a poorly designed function that's hard to use from any code, including C.